# Django: How can I pass a variable into the url from an anchor tag?

Tags: python, django, orm, backend, templatetags

Django again...
I have seen only one way to do this but I am getting an error.

I have the url:

```
url(r'^wish_item/(?P<id>\d#)$', views.wish_item, name="wish_item")
```

and the view,

```
def wish_item(request, id):
```

but the anchor tag in my template is causing me a NoReverseMatch.

```
{% for x in myitems %}
<a href="{% url 'wish_item' %}?id={{x.id}}">{{x.item}}</a>
{% endfor %}
```

What is the correct way to pass the variable  into the url? Is anything wrong with the regex in my url or am I writing this wrong in the template tag? both?

EDIT:
changed the template tag to

```
<a href="{% url 'wish_item' id=x.id %}">{{x.item}}</a>
```

but I still get the error (after clearing the url to just /wish_item because the regex gave me an error also):

```
Reverse for 'wish_item' with keyword arguments '{u'id': 1}' not found. 1 pattern(s) tried: ['wish_item']
```

Comment: The argument is part of the path, not a query param: `{% url 'wish_item' id=x.id %}`

Comment: So I've changed the templatetags to this format. But I'm still getting an error. There must be something wrong with my url.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's getting longer than comments allow, so:

1. The argument is part of the path, not a query param: `{% url 'wish_item' id=x.id %}`
2. Your regexp is (very likely to be) wrong.

   ```
   (?P<id>\d#)
   ```

   This accepts exactly one digit followed by exactly one hash sign. Probably you meant this?

   ```
   (?P<id>\d+)
   ```

   That is, one or more digits?
   For reference, you have the full regex syntax [over here](https://docs.python.org/3/library/re.html#regular-expression-syntax). By the way, if you just have a numeric id, I suggest sticking to this:

   ```
   (?P<id>[0-9]+)
   ```

   The difference is `\d` will also accepts other characters marked as digits in unicode, which you probably won't handle later on.